# RTF to plain text in SQL with read only permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, rtf, plaintext

I have a MSSQL 2005 database which also stores RTF-like text format. I'd like to strip off all formatting code and just get the plain text. Now the tricky part; I only have read access to the database. So, unfortunately I can't use any `CREATE FUNCTION` solutions...

For example, a column starts with something like:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1043\ul\b\f0\fs22
```

Can this be done?

Comment: the context is missing. what's your goal? you need to put the cleaned data back into the db? your only tool is sql? last but not least: how you identify the formatting code? do you have the rules?

Comment: Sorry, it's for reporting. I'm getting various types of data requests. But now most of the data isn't very readable for the end user. So I'd like to get the data from the database and export it to Excel to redistribute it to the end user.